# (udev rules) Unable to detect bluethooth connection for Magic Mouse

Tags: fedora, rules, udev, magic-mouse

I have this event when the device gets connected but the rule never matches:

```
$udevadm monitor -u -p
...
UDEV  [2452.171028] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/dw-apb-uart.0/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:13/0005:004C:0269.0012/input/input30 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/dw-apb-uart.0/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:13/0005:004C:0269.0012/input/input30
SUBSYSTEM=input
PRODUCT=5/4c/269/192
NAME="Magic Mouse"
PHYS="14:7d:da:4d:ff:d9"
UNIQ="bc:d0:74:c7:69:ab"
PROP=0
EV=1f
KEY=70001 0 0 0 0
REL=1943
ABS=273800000000000
MSC=10
MODALIAS=input:b0005v004Cp0269e0192-e0,1,2,3,4,k100,110,111,112,r0,1,6,8,B,C,a2F,30,31,34,35,36,39,m4,lsfw
SEQNUM=9683
USEC_INITIALIZED=2452170577
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_BUS=bluetooth
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1e.0-platform-dw-apb-uart.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1e_0-platform-dw-apb-uart_0
ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1e_0-platform-dw-apb-uart_0
TAGS=:seat:
CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:
```

The udev rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{NAME}=="Magic Mouse", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo Y >> /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_acceleration'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ENV{NAME}=="Magic Mouse", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 50 >> /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_speed'"
```

I tested it with

```
udevadm test --action=add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/dw-apb-uart.0/serial0/serial0-0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:13/0005:004C:0269.0012/input/input30
```

I even applied the changes and tried to see if it'd just work:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
```

I also set the service logs to DEBUG (`udevadm control --log-priority=debug`), and it doesn't run. I tried changing from NAME to UNIQ and using the bluetooth device, but it made no difference. The event happens, but the rule is not matching it.

Any ideas?

Running on Fedora 36.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/62-magicmouse.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="Magic Mouse", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo Y >> /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_acceleration'"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="Magic Mouse", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 50 >> /sys/module/hid_magicmouse/parameters/scroll_speed'"
```

I upgraded to Fedora 37, I don't know if that changed anything, BUT after the upgrade I decided to try again using ATTRS instead of ENV. I also noticed that "name" was in lower case compared to my previous try. It worked fine. I can finally change the magicmouse functionality automatically when I plug it in.